# Game Won't Return to Main Menu Upon Collision

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am working on a collision game as objects move across the screen, but for some reason, it won't return to the main menu when the object collides.  It looks fine to me.  What's wrong here?

```
-(void)Crash {

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(StealthBomber.frame, LargeObstacle1.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(StealthBomber.frame, MediumObstacle1.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(StealthBomber.frame, SmallObstacle1.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(StealthBomber.frame, Grass.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(StealthBomber.frame, Dirt.frame)) {
    [self EndGame];
}
```

}

-(void)EndGame {

```
StealthBomber.hidden = YES;
[timer invalidate];

[self performSelector:@selector(NewGame) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
```

}

-(void)NewGame {

```
LargeObstacle1.hidden = NO;
MediumObstacle1.hidden = NO;
SmallObstacle1.hidden = NO;

StealthBomber.hidden = NO;
StealthBomber.center = CGPointMake(32, 92);
StealthBomber.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"stealthbomber.png"];

startGame = YES;
```

}

Comment: Set breakpoints in `EndGame` ,`NewGame` and `Crash` to see if they are ever called. Also, the code you've posted doesn't say anything about returning to a main menu. Unless that's a typo, your problem is that you're calling `NewGame` from `EndGame` and not whatever method should be returning you to the main menu.

Comment: I fixed the issue after searching using the word finder.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue.  It was a matter of not showing hidden items and hiding other items when newGame is called.